# Is including parameter in params redundant, when also using @RequestPram?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request

In a example like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/artists", params = "genre")
public List<Artist> getArtists(@RequestParam String genre) {
}
```

is including `genre` in the `params` redundant since it is also declared using `@RequestParam` in  the method signature ?

When trying to map to **different methods** for the **same URL**, is the method signature the one that metters, or is also defining `params` necessary?

Comment: why don't you give it a try and see what happens. just remove genre params and see if the control is still coming to this method

Comment: I tried it out, it could not differentiate looking only on the @RequestParams. Maybe it should though.

Answer (score 2):

In the [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) annotation (and other HTTP method specific variants), the [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) element is meant for narrowing the request mappings based on query parameter conditions. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--):

> The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.
>
> Same format for any environment: a sequence of `myParam=myValue` style expressions, with a request only mapped if each such parameter is found to have the given value. Expressions can be negated by using the `!=` operator, as in `myParam!=myValue`. `myParam` style expressions are also supported, with such parameters having to be present in the request (allowed to have any value). Finally, `!myParam` style expressions indicate that the specified parameter is *not* supposed to be present in the request.

In the other hand, the [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation allows you to bind a query parameter to a method argument.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers) for details.